# MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Cannot replace MainPage root?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

Where can I find a good example `MasterDetailPage` for `Xamarin Forms` and `MvvmCross`. 
As my project issues this error:

> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxException: Cannot replace MainPage root?

Have a look at my code:
[source](https://github.com/lwanenko/cryptonext/tree/master/CryptoNextForms/src)

Comment: Don't worry about such negative reaction to your question. You just should get use to it: MvvmCross is a nice framework, but almost has no actual and handy documentation as many other frameworks have, and most of MvvmCross "mega-gurus" just referring to the "dive into the sources" and "search for examples inside of our github yourself" instructions.

Comment: That even gets "funnier" after the fact, that I am experiencing this very exception exactly after looking at the Playground code (MvvmCross/Projects/Playground) and got to this stackoverflow article to resolve it easier. Apparently that's because I need to have *even closer* look at the Playground, but that's just because, again, lack of appropriate documentation. So, just dive into sources, have fun!

Answer (score 2):

As of MvvCross v6.1.2 the issue is still actual, but in general is rather wouldn't be specified as "bug" (so, not sure if it will be changed in any way in next releases or not).

There is obviously too few information regarding the conditions you receive this exception, but **one of the reasons** can be that **you might haven't defined Title value for the Master (Menu) page** inside of xaml.

```
    Title="Never seen and never used title which still throws the exception"
```

From my understanding, MvvmCross has some internal logic which throws that exception, as defining the Menu page means creating (explicitly) MasterDetails wrapper-page, which need to obtain some title, but still, that title isn't seen as the title of Details page is used.

---

Just in case, adding here some **roadmap of organizing MasterDetails pages flow with MvvmCross**:

There must be two parts of the MasterDetails page:

Menu (which is initially is a MasterPage, i.e., some layout wrapped into the MasterDetails page):

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Master, 
    WrapInNavigationPage = false, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class HomeMasterDetailMenuPage : MvxContentPage<HomeMasterDetailMenuViewModel>
```

and actually the content page:

```
[MvxMasterDetailPagePresentation(Position = MasterDetailPosition.Detail, 
    WrapInNavigationPage = true, NoHistory = true)]
public partial class HomeMasterDetailRootPage : MvxContentPage<HomeMasterDetailRootViewModel>
```

Xaml (design) files have a definition which any regular MvvmCross XF Content page has (again, **just don't forget to add `Title` property for the Menu page definition**).

ViewModels of all the pages mentioned are also defined as regular ViewModels - no tricks here.

The only trick is to activate the navigation to that(those) pages as here from some other ViewModel:

```
    private async Task ProcessLogin()
    {
        await NavigationService.Navigate<HomeMasterDetailMenuViewModel>();
        await NavigationService.Navigate<HomeMasterDetailRootViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the playground app for `MvvmCross`, then try to get its sources again, maybe the issue already resolved according to [this comment](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2577#issuecomment-376572475)

Comment: I wouldn't put this note as answer. It doesn't say anything regarding the issue itself.